# Java. Получение родительского элемента

Tags: java, javafx

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с проблемой в реализации определенной механики в игре. 
Итак, у меня имеется класс,в котором я создаю поле для игры. В этом классе у нас есть двумерный массив Pane[5][18],который представляет из себя поле 5 на 18. Предположим,в Pane[2][2] я заношу определенный элемент. Для этого элемента у меня есть другой класс, (наследующийся от класса Pane) в котором я хочу реализовать механику движения на клетку вперед по таймеру.
Собственно,вот функция:

```
public void startMove() {
    timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(moveSpeed), ev -> {
        if(this.getParent()!=null) {
            Pane parent = (Pane) this.getParent();
            parent.getChildren().remove(this); 
        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

Собственно,проблема в том,я получил родительский Pane[2][2],и из него я удалить элемент могу. Но теперь мне нужно получить Pane[2][3],и занести в него мой элемент. Как это можно реализовать не передавая в функцию сам массив?

Comment: Pane[5][18] - массив статический?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович , нет, не статический

Comment: Ладно, а каким образом вы вообще изначально заносите дочерний элемент в массив родительского?

Comment: В классе с созданием самого поля игры,по нажатию на сам Pane (в моем случае, на Pane[2][2])

Comment: я просто не понимаю, что мешает вам в родительском классе создать метод типа move, который принимает 2 инта - движение по оси х,у. и пусть родительский класс в своем методе, исходя из переданных значений в своем же массиве прочитает элемент, потом его из массива удалит, высчитает нужную ячейку по переданным координатам и этот объект туда запишет. тем более у вас есть дочерний класс, который этот метод еще и про наследству получит. вы его не переопределяя можете вызвать и всех делов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, тут в логике проблема. Элемент не должен сам себя удалять. Это должен делать контроллер, как по мне.

То есть, создайте интерфейс типо:

```
public interface LocationChanged {
     void onLocationChanged(Pane pane);
}
```

Реализуйте его в вашем классе, который поле создаёт:

```
public MyController implements LocationChanged  {

    public void onLocationChanged(Pane pane) {
        // этот ваш класс имеет доступ ко всему полю
        // удаляйте из старой ячейки
        // добавляйте в новую
    }
}
```

При создании экземпляра вашей ячейки прокидывайте туда ссылку на ваш контроллер, а в методе `startMove` вызывайте этот колбек.

```
public class MyPane extends Pane {

     private LocationChanged  mListener;
     public MyPane (LocationChanged  listener) {
          mListener = listener;
     }

    public void startMove() {
         timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(moveSpeed), ev -> {
             mListener.onLocationChanged(this);
         }));
         timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
         timeline.play();
    }


}
```